# shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: An exception while trying to list a directory after mounting

Tags: azure, exception, pyspark, azure-databricks, mount-point

I am getting below exception,

*shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details*

First I mounted the directory in dbfs like below,

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"wasbs://{containerName}@{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/a",
  extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.sas.{containerName}.{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net": sasKey}
)
```

then I did,

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/a")
```

I see below reason,

*Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$WrappingIterator.hasNext(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:158)
at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.listInternal(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2444)
... 41 more
Caused by: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87)
at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196)
at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)*

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: You need to expand error, and see for lines like "Caused by"

Comment: Added the caused by in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened due to wrong SAS key configuration which did not have all permissions for the container. The issue has been resolved after giving right SAS key with all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The real error this: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission" - the most probably cause is that you don't have "Blob Contributor" permission that is different from the "Contributor" permission that is set when you create a storage account.

Comment: It happened due to wrong SAS configuration and now the issue has been resolved after the problem lies with the SAS token. However thank you for your response!